# Using Nested Dictionaries in Python -- combining two datasets with a common 'key' and different other variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two csv datasets with county level data. Each dataset identifies the county by a FIPS code. I want to create a nested 'master' dictionary such that I can call it with an identifying FIPS code and it will return the corresonding 'inner' dictionary for that FIPS, which contains all the information from both datasets.

I understand the general way to set up nested dictionaries, namely:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['dict1'] = {}
>>> d['dict1']['innerkey'] = 'value'
>>> d
{'dict1': {'innerkey': 'value'}}
```

But I don't know how to generalize that and populate it from data read in from two separate csvs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you define your master dictionary as:

```
master = {}
```

First, iterate over your smaller data set *foo* so that you can populate the *master* dictionary using the FIPS code for the key, and storing its data under the `'foo'` key:

```
for row in foo_csv_reader:
    fips_code = row[...] # Row storing FIPS code.
    inner_data = {}
    inner_data['foo'] = ... # Data from foo CSV.
    master[fips_code] = inner_data
```

Now, iterate over your larger data set *bar* so that you can populate the *master* dictionary using the matching FIPS code encountered from the previous data set, and storing its data under the `'bar'` key:

```
for row in bar_csv_reader:
    fips_code = row[...] # Row storing FIPS code.
    if fips_code in master:
        inner_data = master[fips_code]
        inner_data['bar'] = ... # Data from bar CSV.
```